# JS: Return a number to a specified power of 10

Tags: javascript, math

I'm working on a problem that requires me to return a number rounded to a specified power of 10. For example:

```
1234, specified power = 2 => 1200
1234, specified power = 3 => 1000
```

I did find a solution to the problem with this function:

```
const roundToPower = (num, pow) => {
    return Math.round(num / Math.pow(10, pow)) * Math.pow(10,pow)
};
```

However, I am not exactly sure how and why it works.

Is someone able to break it down for me? Thanks!

Comment: Do you know what [`Math.pow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow) does? Try thinking through how `Math.round(num / 10) * 10` works.

Comment: Place each of the calculations like `Math.pow(10, pow)`, `Math.round(x/y)` and `value * Math.pow()` to separate variables and check each value. Write these values on paper and calculate them if it helps. Read the documentation for each of those methods.

Comment: Writing it out on paper cleared it up for me - Thanks!

Comment: @suuuriam Answer to `1234, specified power = 2 => 1230` should be `1200` I think.

Comment: Yes, absolutely - thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets divide the upper function into three parts

1. `num / Math.pow(10, pow)`  will divide the given number by the power of 10 which is given. e.g for `pow = 3` `num` will be divided by `1000`
2. It then uses use `Math.round()` on that decimal.
3. Then again to equalize the division we did in first step it multiples again with power of ten `Math.pow(10,pow)`

#### Example

For `pow = 3` and `num = 1230`

```
=> Math.round(1230 / Math.pow(10, 3)) * Math.pow(10, 3)
=> Math.round(1230 / 1000 )) * 1000
=> Math.round( 1.230 )) * 1000
=> 1 * 1000
=> 1000
```

Answer (score 1):

I know that question is not about how to convert numbers to a specified power of 10. I know a better and simple way to do this. Maybe it can help.

```js
let a = 1234;
a = convert(a,2);
console.log(a); // 1200

let b = 123456;
b = convert(b,5);
console.log(b); //123460



function convert(num, power){

  if(power < String(num).length){
    num = num.toPrecision(power);
    num = Number(num).toFixed();
    return num;
  }
  else{
    console.log("Invalid power for number: " + num);
  }
}
```